# Founding a Religion in a city that already has one

Tags: civilization-6

In Civilization VI can I found a religion in a city that already has one? Will the city have the just-founded Religion, despite it having only one follower, or will it stick to the religion of most of its citizens, effectively pre-emptying the spread of the new Religion?

Civilopedia seems to say conflicting things about this:

Founding your Religion:
"Once your Religion is founded, all of your cities with Holy Sites will automatically convert to the Religion"

Religious Units and Pressure
"If more than half the citizens in the city are Followers of a particular Religion and that Religion has the majority of Followers in that city, that Religion will become predominant in that city"

So, which of these effects predominate?

Comment: `Civilopedia seems to say conflicting things about this.` elaborate on this please :)

Comment: Whenever I did this the city switched to my religion. However I'm not sure what happened to the existing believers.

Comment: @treyBake edited in more details. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I have encountered a situation where I converted a neighbor's entire empire before they founded a religion. The only victory condition was Religious. Eventually the neighbor (Amanitore) did eventually found her own religion and eventually convert her cities to it.
I think what's required is simply enough great prophet points to recruit a prophet.

Comment: I don't see the conflict. It looks like you are asking if the Prophet will spawn with the pre-existing religion of the city? But in Civ VI Prophets don't have a "religion" like they did in previous games, they are just a Great Person that you spend to start a Religion. The quoted sections literally explain what happens. You found the religion, and your cities with Holy Sites convert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

To found a religion, you need a prophet. You can only ever gain one prophet. Hence, the religion present in the city you want to found your religion in, and thus make it your holy city, is the religion of another player.

Once you found your religion, all your cities with holy cites convert to your religion as states in the Civilopedia. There is no conflict with the entries you stated. The conflict arises from your assumption that the cities would gain your religion by having one citizen of your religion. This is not true. Founding a religion will flip as many citizens as needed to make your religion the majority religion in those cities.